# Fastest way to search a positive number in the last column of a Datatable in C#

Tags: c#

I have a huge datatable. In its last column two types of entries are there; either `0`or`a (where 0< a <=1, all a's are equal)` I need to find the value of `a's and`its count in that column.`Usual`for` loop is taking around 30ms, which I can not afford to spend. Does anyone can think of a tweak here to make it faster?
The sum of that column would always be 1. 
for e.g.

the last column would be

```
[0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5]
```

Responses are appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: You want every distinct value of `a` and the number of occurrences for each value? Does your datatable happen to be sorted on the `a` column? What does the distribution of values typically look like?

Comment: in order to speed it up, you need to index or sort the data.

Comment: @Blorgbeard,  all a's are equal. number of occurrences for a's yes.
Suppose there are 4 rows in a datatable , then consider a= 0.333 and it occurred 3 times and the remaining entry is 0.

Comment: @Jim, I can not sort the data. This order is important.

Comment: @Artiga: Index that column as Jim suggested.

Comment: You mean the sum of all `a` values is always 1? Can you please [edit] your question with a small representative sample dataset? And the desired output for that data.

Comment: So, output would be 0:3, 0.5:2 ?

Comment: yes, you said it right.

Comment: if you index the column, and then count all the values that are `not` zero, you will speed it up. you don't really need to find the value if it's always 1, an index will help you count the number of non zero values faster as long as there are a lot of zeros. There are better data structures than a data table for this problem.

Comment: @Jim, this is the process where in the beginning there will be very less zeros or no zeros. but as process proceeds there will be more and more zeros. Can you please write a sample code and tell me ? thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Can we say then that all "a" values are equal and their sum is equal to 1?
In this case, the number of non-zero values would be equal to 1/a. 
All you would need to do is find the first "a" value and then calculate its inverse. e.g. you could break your for loop as soon as you find a positive value,

```
public int numberOfPositives()
    {
        foreach (myRowClass row in myDataBase.GetTable<myRowClass>())
        {
            if (row.lastColumn > 0) return (int)Math.Round(1 / row.lastColumn,0);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

or, if your table could be ordered by that column you would only need to get the first value and compute its inverse and you wouldn't need a for loop at all.

Comment: that's smart, though the question states `0 > a <= 1` so I don't think they are always equal.

Comment: @donquijote, 

 for (int i = 0; i < my_data.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToDecimal(my_data.Rows[i]["Likelihood"]) > 0)
                {
                    dblDefaultLikelihood = Convert.ToDouble(my_data.Rows[i]["Likelihood"]);
                    break;
                }
            }

isn't this same?
this is what I am trying currently

Comment: if you need to find the last value greater than zero, just run the loop backwards. `for (int i = my_data.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) { ...`

Comment: according to @Artiga comment (third comment in the question) I understood all "a" are equal (this should probably be added to the question). In this case all one needs to do is find the first non-zero number and calculate its inverse. Regarding the use of for instead of foreach I would check that using .Count does not cause another loop over the whole table.

Answer (score 2):

How does this measure up compared to your loop?

```
var t = new DataTable();
t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(decimal)));
t.Rows.Add(.5m);
t.Rows.Add(.5m);
t.Rows.Add(.5m);
t.Rows.Add(0m );
t.Rows.Add(0m );
t.Rows.Add(0m );

// dump is a method provided by linqpad (https://www.linqpad.net/)
t.Compute("COUNT(Value)", "Value > 0").Dump();
t.Compute("SUM(Value)", "Value > 0").Dump();
```

Gives me

```
3
1.5
```

Alternatively you will need a better data structure, for example, a hash table or dictionary containing only the non zero values, and a count of the zero's held elsewhere.

Comment: which namespace have you used for .Dump()?

Comment: `Dump` is just a sample method, I use [linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/) to cut and paste code, and view the results quickly. It's just used to demonstrate the result. You would assign it to a variable and use it in your production code. `var mySum = t.Compute("COUNT(Value)", "Value > 0")`

Comment: it is more time consuming than my method. Takes 90ms. Can you please show how can I use sorting here?

Answer (score 1):

Artiga, I don't know how many values you have.
This sample I created using a `HashSet` sums about ten million positive values in 191 milliseconds.

```
var random = new Random();

var values = new HashSet<decimal>();

int i = 10000000;
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
decimal epsilon = 0.1m;
while (i-- > 0)
{
    var value = (decimal)random.NextDouble();
    // assume values below .1 are zero.
    if (value - epsilon > 0)
        values.Add(value);
}
sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump("create");
sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
values.Count().Dump(Convert.ToString(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
values.Sum().Dump(Convert.ToString(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
```

Gives me

create
4313 (four seconds to create the list - which is a long time...)

0 (zero milliseconds)
8980437 (actual count of values)

191 (191 milliseconds)
4939932.287292723677015 (sum)

Comment: Currently I just have 73921 rows. For this It 112 ms is taking for sorting only. But the Number of rows may increase in future.

Comment: I updated my answer, my timings were off, incorrect stopwatch method, it takes 191ms to sum ten million values, If I do 73000, it takes about 49ms to create the list, and 31ms to sort the list, and 2ms to sum the list. That's a vague measurement on my little laptop. Production figures will vary greatly. If you have to sum the values like this, you could consider batching the values, and summing batches in multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

If your datatable is saved in a database then you can use the following SQL command to get the number of distinct values of a in the column

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ColumnName)
FROM DBNAME
where ColumnName > 0 and ColumnName < 1
```

Get back to me if this is not what you wanted

Comment: no it is not saved into databases, at least for now.

Comment: assuming @donquijote is incorrect, and there is no simple mathematical solution to your problem, putting the data into a fit for purpose indexed structure such as a database will vastly speed up the solution

Comment: it would be very useful if you can insert the whole table into a database...just consider the option if it for a purpose...or if the question is just for knowledge then leave it

Answer (score -1):

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ABC",typeof(double));
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                if (i % 2 != 0)
                {
                    dr[0] = (double)r.Next(0, 2)/i;
                }
                else
                {
                    dr[0] = 0;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            int coutPositiveNumber = dt.AsEnumerable().Count(p => p.Field<double>("ABC")>0);
```

This coutPositiveNumber will give u all positive number Count !